# Why is my react-query query refetching after an unmount/mount operation?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

#### Setup

I have the following `react-query` hook:

```js
const STALE_TIME_MS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 12h

const useUser = () => {
  const services = useServices();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
    'user',
    () => services.user.verify(),
    {
      staleTime: STALE_TIME_MS,
      cacheTime: STALE_TIME_MS,
    }
  );
  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    user: data,
  };
};
```

Then, I have an `App` component as a child lives inside the `QueryClientProvider`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useUser();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Authenticating />;
  }

  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

The `Login` component checks if the user is already logged in and redirects it back to `/`:

```js
const Login = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  if (user) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  ...
}
```

The `Dashboard` component does the reverse:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  if (!user) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }

  ...
};
```

## Problem

When the request that `services.user.verify()` makes fails, `react-query` keeps retrying the `user` query indefinitely. This is despite the fact that `react-query`'s default retries is 3.

[image: Infinite retry]

The problem seems to come from the fact that I am calling `useUser()` from multiple components that are mounting/unmounting. When I remove the redirect logic from `Dashboard` and `Login`, `react-query` retries 3 times and then takes me to the login screen as expected.

[image: One call to useUser]

The interesting fact is that the `user` query is marked as stale. If I change my `services.user.verify()` implementation to return `null` instead of throwing an error when the user is not authenticated, the query is marked as fresh and I don't have this problem at all.

## Questions

- Does `react-query` **always** consider queries stale when they fail even after the retries?
- Does a new component calling the query **always** result in a retry?
- Is there an option to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does react-query always consider queries stale when they fail even after the retries?

Yes. `staleTime` only kicks in for successful queries, and queries that have no data (e.g. because they failed) are considered stale. If your query succeeds once and then fails on a re-fetch, it is not automatically considered stale - `staleTime` matters now because you already have data.

> Does a new component calling the query always result in a retry?

When a component mounts, react-query triggers a fetch. This is due to the flag `refetchOnMount`, so you can customise this flag if you don't want that. retries are triggered depending on the `retry` flag and yes, if a fetch is triggered, retries are triggered accordingly.

> Is there an option to prevent this from happening?
> The problem seems to come from the fact that I am calling useUser() from multiple components that are mounting/unmounting.

Yes, this seems to be the root cause. You can either work around this with the `refetchOnMount` option, or, probably better - don't redirect to a route that calls `useUser` (and expects a user to be present) unless you already have data for that user. You could for example mount the `Login` component if your `useUser` is in error state, because that means your are not authenticated, and only render the `Dashboard` if you have a user.

Comment: Setting `refetchOnMount` to `false` did not work for me. I had to avoid rendering the component calling the `useQuery` to prevent the refetching.

Comment: @TkDodo if I set refetchOnMount to false and there's new data compared to what's in the cache. would it then refetch?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. It will only know that there is new data compared to what's in the cache _after_ that data was already fetched 